# Why do I get a r_frame_rate of 1000/1 in ffmpeg for videos when using MediaRecorder to record getDisplayMedia?

Tags: ffmpeg, framerate

Each time I download a video from a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/thoughtassassin/dufke4y0/36/) that I created the r_frame_rate is reported as 1000/1. However, I set the frameRate constraint to: { ideal: 30, max: 60}. When the stream object is logged in the console, the frame rate is 30.

When I process the downloaded video with ffmpeg the output shows the r_frame_rate as 1000/1 when recorded on an M1 Macbook.

This is the ffmpeg command that I am using:

```
ffprobe -i <video input source here> -show_streams -of json
```